# JQuery: Create new element with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please i am having difficulty creating the flexbox script below dynamically.

```
<div class="Table-row">
    <div class="Table-row-item u-Flex-grow2" data-header="Header1">row2 col1</div>
    <div class="Table-row-item" data-header="Header2">row2 col2</div>
    <div class="Table-row-item" data-header="Header3">row2 col3</div>
    <div class="Table-row-item" data-header="Header4">row2 col4</div>
    <div class="Table-row-item u-Flex-grow3" data-header="Header5">row2 col5</div>
    <div class="Table-row-item" data-header="Header6">row2 col6</div>
    <div class="Table-row-item" data-header="Header7">row2 col7</div>
  </div>
```

In my Jquery i loop through like below.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
   var className = metadata[i].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-") + " Table-row-item";
   var rowElement = $("<div></div>", {class: className, text: data[i]});

   $('.'+className).prop('data-header', 'value');
   rowElement.appendTo($tr);
}
```

The problem is

```
$('.'+className).prop('data-header', 'value');
```

does not add my `data-header` property. I tried adding it like

```
$("<div></div>", {class: className, text: data[i], data-header :'value'})
```

And it throws error.

I tried

```
$('.'+className).attr('data-header', 'value');
```

as explain Here as well and it isn't adding. Please how do i achieve or add the property dynamically ? Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

wrap `data-header` in `'` :-

```
$("<div></div>", { 'class': className, 'text': data[i], 'data-header' :'value'});
```

Another option is to set the `rowElement`:-

```
var rowElement = $("<div></div>", {class: className, text: data[i]});
rowElement.prop('data-header', 'value');
```

or

```
var rowElement = $("<div></div>", {class: className, text: data[i]}).prop('data-header', 'value');
```

`$('.'+className)` will only be available after you `append`.

Though you should use `.data('header', 'value');` to set `data`.

Comment: Thanks man. The last option works for me and it seems not putting the data-header in quotation was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The following code work fine and add the `data` attribute to the element with class `className` :

```
$('.'+className).attr('data-header', 'value');
```

But in your case you can add `rowElement` because the variable is not added to the DOM :

```
$(rowElement).find('.'+className).attr('data-header', 'value');
```

**Note :** Better to use **[data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** instead of `attr` when you want `set` or `get` data attributes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
.attr
```

is not allowed to add custom headers
use

```
.data
```

instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/